# Extracting Client Hello and SNI in libpcap

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming, libpcap, sni

I'm using libpcap library in c to parse pcap files. I'm trying to extract TCP client hello and then check Server Name Indication to match a given server. Can I do that? and if yes, can someone tell me how? thanks

Comment: libpcap only gets you to the network data. From there you need to parse the IP and TCP protocols to get to the TLS layer and then you need to understand this layer to extract the ClientHello which then contains the SNI extension. Thus, by just using libpcap you are about at 5% of the way only which makes this question too broad.

Comment: I did parse TCP and IP protocols, but how do I know that this packet is a ClientHello?

Comment: So how did you know that you are dealing with IP and TCP? Probably by understanding these protocols and extracting the information accordingly. And the same you need to do with TLS to get the ClientHello: see [RFC 5246](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246) for the specification of TLS 1.2 which also describes the format of the ClientHello.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C++ code snippet that can do that using the [PcapPlusPlus](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus) library. This code assumes you're reading packets from a pcap file, but the same can be achieved when reading from a live interface:

```
// create a pcap file reader instance
pcpp::IFileReaderDevice* reader = pcpp::IFileReaderDevice::getReader("my_ssl_packets.pcap");

// open the reader for reading
reader->open();

// read the first (and only) packet from the file
pcpp::RawPacket rawPacket;
while (reader->getNextPacket(rawPacket) != NULL)
{
    // parse the packet
    pcpp::Packet sslParsedPacket(&rawPacket);

    // check if this is a SSL packet
    if (!sslParsedPacket.isPacketOfType(pcpp::SSL))
        continue;

    // check if this is a SSL handshake packet
    pcpp::SSLHandshakeLayer* sslHandshakeLayer = sslPacket->getLayerOfType<pcpp::SSLHandshakeLayer>();
    if (sslHandshakeLayer == NULL)
        continue;

    // check if this is a client-hello message
    pcpp::SSLClientHelloMessage* clientHelloMessage = sslHandshakeLayer->getHandshakeMessageOfType<pcpp::SSLClientHelloMessage>();
    if (clientHelloMessage == NULL)
        continue;

    // extract the Server Name Indication from the client-hello message
    pcpp::SSLServerNameIndicationExtension* sniExtension = clientHelloMessage->getExtensionOfType<pcpp::SSLServerNameIndicationExtension>();
    if (sniExtension != NULL)
        printf("Server Name Indication is: %s\n", sniExtension->getHostName().c_str());
}

// close the file reader
reader->close();
delete reader;
```